# Find minimum swaps to strictly sort 2 arrays where you can only swap ith element of A with jth element of B

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Given 2 Arrays A & B, find the minimum number of swaps needed to strictly sort both arrays.

I know there are various questions similar to this here such as: [Relative sorting with minimum possible swaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245361/relative-sorting-with-minimum-possible-swaps) but the constrains in these questions only allow swaps between ith element of array A and B.

How do I go about doing this if the constrain was changed  to be able to swap with any element of A to any element of B (i.e The swaps can be performed on any ith element of A with any jth element of B)

Lets say the arrays are:
A: [9,3,3,2,1]
B: [5,6,7,8]

The minimum number of swaps that I can get (manually by hand) is 4.

Swap #1 (swap 1 with 8)

A: [9,3,3,2,8]

B: [5,6,7,1]

Swap #2 (swap 9 with 1)

A: [1,3,3,2,8]

B: [5,6,7,9]

Swap #3 (swap 2 with 5)

A: [1,3,3,5,8]

B: [2,6,7,9]

Swap #4 (swap 3 with 2)

A: [1,2,3,5,8]

B: [3,6,7,9]

P.S I am unsure if this is the minimum as I have no clue how to begin this.

Thank you.

Comment: For this particular example it can be proven that the minimum is 3, but  I have no idea for a solution for *any* input. Maybe this could turn out to be an NP-hard problem. Also, when a particular value occurs three times or more, there is no solution.

Comment: May I ask how did you get the minimum, 3 to get the above example strictly sorted? I haven been trying but I am unable to find a way to get minimum of 3.

Comment: I was wrong, 4 is the minimum. In A, you can see that numbers 1 and 2 cannot stay where they are, since they are the overall smallest. Similarly, 9 cannot stay where it is, because it is the greatest. Finally, one of the two 3s has to move, because duplicates are not allowed in the same array. So we have at least four numbers that need to move. One swap can only change one number in A at a time, so the minimum is 4.